# Match strings in between without returning start and end

Tags: python, regex

I have following style of string:

```
line = '242322342343-gewe|gu_w=23423526,29845903458,3244;tu_w=2234234;'
```

I want to match elements that are in between `gu_w=` and `;`but after match I don't want `gu_w` and `;` to be in the result:

```
re.compile(r'gu_w=(.*?);', re.I | re.U)
```

above expression will return:

```
gu_w=23423526,29845903458,3244;
```

but how do I get regex to return `23423526,29845903458,3244`

I was thinking strip the results after matching but is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be doing `.group(0)`, which returns the entire match.  You should be accessing capture group `1` instead.  This will return only the text matched by `(.*?)`:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = '242322342343-gewe|gu_w=23423526,29845903458,3244;tu_w=2234234;'
>>> pat = re.compile(r'gu_w=(.*?);', re.I | re.U)
>>> pat.search(line).group(1)
'23423526,29845903458,3244'
>>>
```

Below is an excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group):

> `match.group([group1, ...])`
>
> Returns one or more subgroups of the match...**If a
>   `groupN` argument is zero, the corresponding return value is the entire
>   matching string**; if it is in the inclusive range `[1..99]`, it is the string matching the corresponding parenthesized group.

Comment: shoot i was indeed doing group.

Comment: @How would i give a name to the group `re.compile(r'(?P<gu>gu_w=(.*?);)', re.I | re.U)` this will return entire thing.

Comment: Use `.group(2)` since you put the capture group in another capture group.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to iCodez's answer, you could also use lookarounds to handle the boundaries.

```
re.compile(r"""
    (?<=gu_w=)    # assert literal gu_w=
    .*?           # match anything, non-greedily
    (?=;)         # assert literal ;""", re.I | re.U | re.X)
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex:

```
gu_w=([^;]+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fE6kA0/2)

will match between the anchors without including them.

Python demo:

```
>>> st='242322342343-gewe|gu_w=23423526,29845903458,3244;tu_w=2234234;'
>>> re.search(r'gu_w=([^;]+)', st).group(1) 
'23423526,29845903458,3244'
```

You can also use named capture groups to make your intent more clear:

```
>>> seeking='gu_w'
>>> m=re.search(r'{0}=(?P<{0}>[^;]+)'.format(seeking), st)
>>> m.group(seeking)
'23423526,29845903458,3244'
```

Or,

```
>>> m.groupdict()
{'gu_w': '23423526,29845903458,3244'}
```